# Installing Debian on a Toshiba Satellite laptop

Tags: debian, debian-installer

first of all, I am trying to install Debian on a Toshiba Satellite C50-BCNTN01 with Intel Celeron Processor N2830.

I have the Debian amd64 install disc (full, no network downloads necessary - ver 8, "Jessie"), but when I boot up my computer (to install), all I get is a black screen that reads:

"Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

Right now, I am running windows, which came pre-installed with the laptop (and I'd like to change that).

Is it possible that it isn't compatible with my device? If so, which version of Linux would you recommend?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you actually did. Did you actually install from the Debian disk, or have you just booted from it? "I have the Debian amd64 install disc (full, no network downloads necessary), but when I boot up my computer..." is vague.

Comment: which version of debian would also be useful

Answer (score 2):

grub (the boot loader) cannot find one of normal.mod, menu.lst or grub.cfg. My first thought is that the disk got corrupted either in the download or while burning. Did you check any of the checksums?

Comment: Not sure what that means, exactly. However, I torrented the .ISO via official torrent release on the debian website and then verified the burn with imgburn and the verify checked out.

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that GRUB2 configuration files got corrupted, this could be due to a bad ISO file you used to install it. At first I'd recommend that you download again the Debian ISO image, burn it and check the integrity after burned and try the installation with the new image.

If you want to skip that, follow this fix where you will use **boot-repair** to get GRUB2 files reinstalled so you can boot Debian properly:

**Fix Minimal BASH like line editing is supported GRUB Error In Linux**

http://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/

Comment: Hmmm, I already checked the integrity via imgburn, and torrented the .iso via an official torrent on the debian website.

Would you recommend I verify the signature of the .iso? Or just go ahead with boot-repair?

Comment: Please do. Check ISO's signature just to ensure it's OK to use, then you can move forward with boot-repair.

Answer (score 0):

Running Debian 8 on a Toshiba Satellite C55-C5241. Try accessing your BIOS (hold down F2 when booting) and look for an option called: Secure Boot. Make sure is disabled.